# Neo4j: meaning of the iterations in the result of the Label Propagation Algorithm (LPA)

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I ran the LPA and I have the following results:

[image]

What means ranIterations = 9 ? Is one iteration meaning that the label goes to the next node ? I read the documentation but I'm not sure if I understood it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/label-propagation/) is pretty clear:

> At every iteration of propagation, each node updates its label to the
> one that the maximum numbers of its neighbours belongs to. Ties are
> broken arbitrarily but deterministically.